# How to add "show more" button at the end of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-viewholder

This is the screen I have to create:

[image]

The problem is this ">" icon at the end of the list. I'm not sure if it has to be above the list, like floating button or should it be a part of last item in the list (like frame layout with image above image)? Not really sure.

I'll post my layouts and adapter and I'd like to ask you if someone had a similar task/problem.

Activity's layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarImageDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/imageDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/thumbnail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_image_number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/imageDetails"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        tools:text="1 of 7" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:background="@color/button_grey"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/imageDetails"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" />


    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_details" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the layout of Adapter's ViewHolder:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageHolder"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/thumbnail" />
```

And this is my Adapter:

```
    class ImageDetailsAdapter(private val context: Context, private val listener: ImageDetailsIconClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageDetailsAdapter.ImageDetailsViewHolder>() {
    private val imagesList = ArrayList<String>()

    fun setImages(images: List<String>) {
        imagesList.clear()
        imagesList.addAll(images)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageDetailsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_image_details, parent, false)
        return ImageDetailsViewHolder(view, context)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageDetailsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val imageUrl = getImage(position)
        if (imageUrl != null) {
            holder.loadImage(imageUrl)
        }
    }

    private fun getImage(position: Int): String? {
        return if (imagesList.isEmpty()) null else imagesList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imagesList.size
    }

    inner class ImageDetailsViewHolder(itemView: View, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageHolder)

        init {
            imageView.setOnClickListener { listener.onImageClick(adapterPosition) }
        }

        fun loadImage(imageUrl: String) {
            GlideApp.with(context)
                    .load(GlideUrl(imageUrl, AuthentificationGlideHeaders.headers))
                    .error(R.drawable.show_more_btn_background)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_home)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple layouts with RecycleView with the last item is add more view.
Check this article: http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-different-layouts/

Comment: this would add the view to the end of the list, any way we could add it on top of the last item of the list? using viewholder and view type method ?

Comment: Yes and Yes. view type used to identify which view-holder to be used.